# getting user and tweet ID from url using JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter

So I have tweet url for example `https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976`.
This url in my website gets automatically parsed to

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976">https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976</a>
```

I need to match this pattern and also get username and tweet ID.
I did it that way 
`/<a href="(http|https):\/\/twitter.com\/([^\/]*)\/status\/([^\/]*)">.+<\/a>/g`. Everything works when I have 1 tweet per line, but if there are 2 or more tweets in one line, that regex matches both of them at same time and groups it as one, but I need to separate them.
Example:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976">https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976</a>

<a href="https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976">https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976</a>
```

returns 2 matches, but

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976">https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976</a><a href="https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976">https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/423771542627966976</a>
```

returns 1 match including both urls. How can I separate it or for example everything after  interpret as new line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's best to avoid parsing HTML with regex when possible. Having said that the problem with your expression is the greedy `.+` which will match as much as possible. Instead you could use `.+?` to make it ungreedy (match as few characters as possible). Or you could restrict what `.` matches, for example use `[^\s<>]+` instead of `.+`.

Also you probably want to change those `[^\/]*` to maybe `[^\/"\s]*` to make them more effective.